# Forbid mongodb not authenticated connect

Tags: mongodb

If to run mongo with authorization (i.e mongod --auth) it still allows to connect using client mongo and get to mongo cli where one will get refused to execute any command.

But I wonder if it is possible to close such connection for the unauthenticated user so one does not see mongo cli at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new connection to MongoDB has two key aspects:

1. establishing a connection
2. authenticating the connection

As at MongoDB 3.4, the source IPs that are able to establish a connection are determined by  your firewall settings. There is also a `bindIp` setting for MongoDB which determines which network interface(s) `mongod` listens to.

Once a connection is established, access control and authentication is managed by your MongoDB configuration.

In your example, you are able to connect via the `mongo` shell because the source IP is not blocked by firewall configuration. Assuming access control is enabled and authentication has been properly configured, establishing a connection to MongoDB does not provide any access to data.

For more information on best practices, see the [MongoDB Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/).